# Microsoft SQL Server 2016 DLLs

Tags: .net, frameworks

I have a project solution with a SQL Server 2016 database, and I need to complete my framework with some DLLs that I don't find on the internet, and some ones are not free to download.

Specifically I need to get these dlls:

```
ConnectionInfo
SQLTask
ForEachAdoEnumerator
ForEachFromVarEnumerator
ForEachNodeListEnumerator
ForEachSMOEnumerator
ManagedConnections
```

Can you help me to find these DLLs and download them before running my project on Visual Studio? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the [SQL Server Management Objects](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects/) available on NuGet

Comment: Thank you marc for your feedback :) SQL server Managment Objects contains all the dlls that i'm looking for ?